# How to understand expain analyze output for query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I have this query in my database:

```sql
       INSERT INTO value2s(organization,
          location,
          device,
          measurement,
          timestamp,
          interval,
          average,
          max,
          min,
          stdev,
          created_at,
          updated_at)
   
   SELECT organization,
          location,
          device,
          measurement,
          timestamp,
          interval,
          average,
          max,
          min,
          stdev,
          NOW(),
          NOW()
        FROM
           (SELECT
               split_part(topic,'/', 1) organization,
               split_part(topic,'/', 2) location,
               split_part(topic,'/', 3) device,
               split_part(topic,'/', 4) measurement,
               high_margin timestamp,
               86400 interval,
               SUM(prev_value::DECIMAL * EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timestamp - prev_timestamp))/86400 average,
               MAX(value::DECIMAL) max,
               MIN(value::DECIMAL) min,
               STDDEV(value::DECIMAL) stdev
           FROM (
               SELECT
                   topic,
                   value,
                   timestamp,
                   low_margin,
                   high_margin,
                   lag(timestamp,1) OVER (PARTITION BY topic ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC) prev_timestamp,
                   lag(value,1) OVER (PARTITION BY topic ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ASC) prev_value
               FROM (
                   (
                       SELECT
                           m1.topic,
                           m1.value,
                           m1.timestamp,
                           to_timestamp(floor(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM m1.timestamp) / 86400) * 86400) at time zone 'UTC' low_margin,
                           to_timestamp(floor(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM m1.timestamp) / 86400 +1) * 86400) at time zone 'UTC' high_margin
                       FROM mqtt_logs m1
                       WHERE topic = 'uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state'
                            AND timestamp >= COALESCE((
                                SELECT v2.timestamp
                                FROM value2s v2
                                WHERE 'uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state' = v2.organization || '/' || v2.location || '/' || v2.device || '/' || v2.measurement || '/state' 
                                AND 
                                interval = 86400
                                ORDER BY v2.timestamp DESC
                                LIMIT 1 
                            ),to_timestamp(0))
                   ) UNION (
                       SELECT
                           m.topic,
                           m.value,
                           max.high_margin timestamp,
                           to_timestamp(floor(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM m.timestamp) / 86400) * 86400) at time zone 'UTC' low_margin,
                           to_timestamp(floor(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM m.timestamp) / 86400 +1) * 86400) at time zone 'UTC' high_margin
                       FROM mqtt_logs m
                       INNER JOIN (
                           SELECT
                               topic,
                               MAX(timestamp) lts,
                               to_timestamp(floor(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM timestamp) / 86400 +1) * 86400) at time zone 'UTC' high_margin
                           FROM mqtt_logs
                           WHERE topic = 'uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state'
                           AND timestamp >= COALESCE((
                               SELECT v2.timestamp
                               FROM value2s v2
                               WHERE 'uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state' = v2.organization || '/' || v2.location || '/' || v2.device || '/' || v2.measurement || '/state' 
                               AND 
                               interval = 86400
                               ORDER BY v2.timestamp DESC
                               LIMIT 1 
                           ),to_timestamp(0))
                           GROUP BY high_margin,topic
                       ) as max ON max.lts = m.timestamp AND max.topic = m.topic
                       WHERE m.topic = 'uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state'
                       AND m.timestamp >= COALESCE((
                           SELECT v2.timestamp
                           FROM value2s v2
                           WHERE 'uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state' = v2.organization || '/' || v2.location || '/' || v2.device || '/' || v2.measurement || '/state' 
                           AND 
                           interval = 86400
                           ORDER BY v2.timestamp DESC
                           LIMIT 1 
                       ),to_timestamp(0))
                   )
               ) m2
           ) m3
           GROUP BY high_margin,topic
           HAVING high_margin < (
               SELECT m5.timestamp
               FROM mqtt_logs m5
               WHERE m5.topic = m3.topic
               ORDER BY m5.timestamp DESC
               LIMIT 1
           )
           AND topic = 'uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state'
           AND high_margin >= COALESCE((
               SELECT v2.timestamp
               FROM value2s v2
               WHERE 'uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state' = v2.organization || '/' || v2.location || '/' || v2.device || '/' || v2.measurement || '/state' 
               AND 
               interval = 86400
               ORDER BY v2.timestamp DESC
               LIMIT 1 
           ),to_timestamp(0))
       ) m6
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM value2s AS vs
       where m6.organization = vs.organization
       AND   m6.location = vs.location
       AND  m6.device = vs.device
       AND   m6.measurement = vs.measurement
       AND   m6.timestamp = vs.timestamp
       AND m6.interval = vs.interval
   )
   ;
```

which is running slowly on my server (approx 600ms).

I ran `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the query and got these results:

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                        

 Insert on value2s  (cost=25397.09..674338.14 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=708.374..708.386 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=25397.09..674338.14 rows=294 width=196) (actual time=708.373..708.385 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=25396.67..673037.94 rows=299 width=300) (actual time=708.372..708.383 rows=0 loops=1)
               Group Key: m3.high_margin, m3.topic
               Filter: (m3.high_margin < (SubPlan 1))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1
               InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..1583.05 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.052..0.053 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan Backward using index_value2s_on_timestamp_and_interval on value2s v2  (cost=0.29..4748.56 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.049..0.050 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: ("interval" = 86400)
                             Filter: ('uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state'::text = ((((((((organization)::text || '/'::text) || (location)::text) || '/'::text) || (device)::text) || '/'::text) || (measurement)::text) || '/state'::text))
                             Rows Removed by Filter: 11
               ->  Sort  (cost=23813.62..23821.22 rows=3041 width=120) (actual time=701.272..701.348 rows=1704 loops=1)
                     Sort Key: m3.high_margin
                     Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 288kB
                     ->  Subquery Scan on m3  (cost=23295.58..23637.69 rows=3041 width=120) (actual time=699.934..701.033 rows=1704 loops=1)
                           Filter: (m3.high_margin >= COALESCE(($1)::timestamp with time zone, '1970-01-01 02:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone))
                           ->  WindowAgg  (cost=23295.58..23500.85 rows=9123 width=128) (actual time=699.877..700.713 rows=1704 loops=1)
                                 ->  Sort  (cost=23295.58..23318.39 rows=9123 width=80) (actual time=699.860..699.951 rows=1704 loops=1)
                                       Sort Key: m2."timestamp"
                                       Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 288kB
                                       ->  Subquery Scan on m2  (cost=22513.04..22695.50 rows=9123 width=80) (actual time=699.163..699.522 rows=1704 loops=1)
                                             ->  HashAggregate  (cost=22513.04..22604.27 rows=9123 width=88) (actual time=699.160..699.422 rows=1704 loops=1)
                                                   Group Key: m1.topic, m1.value, m1."timestamp", ((to_timestamp(((floor((EXTRACT(epoch FROM m1."timestamp") / '86400'::numeric)) * '86400'::numeric))::double precision) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'::text)), ((to_timestamp(((floor(((EXTRACT(epoch FROM m1."timestamp") / '86400'::numeric) + '1'::numeric)) * '86400'::numeric))::double precision) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'::text))
                                                   Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 665kB
                                                   ->  Append  (cost=1893.67..22399.01 rows=9123 width=88) (actual time=681.498..698.512 rows=1704 loops=1)
                                                         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on mqtt_logs m1  (cost=1893.67..8070.57 rows=8888 width=71) (actual time=681.496..684.538 rows=1703 loops=1)
                                                               Recheck Cond: ((topic)::text = 'uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state'::text)
                                                               Filter: ("timestamp" >= COALESCE(($2)::timestamp with time zone, '1970-01-01 02:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone))
                                                               Rows Removed by Filter: 24522
                                                               Heap Blocks: exact=5359
                                                               InitPlan 3 (returns $2)
                                                                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..1583.05 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.103..0.104 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                                       ->  Index Scan Backward using index_value2s_on_timestamp_and_interval on value2s v2_1  (cost=0.29..4748.56 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.093..0.094 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                                             Index Cond: ("interval" = 86400)
                                                                             Filter: ('uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state'::text = ((((((((organization)::text || '/'::text) || (location)::text) || '/'::text) || (device)::text) || '/'::text) || (measurement)::text) || '/state'::text))
                                                                             Rows Removed by Filter: 11
                                                               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_mqtt_logs_on_topic_and_unit  (cost=0.00..308.39 rows=26663 width=0) (actual time=0.704..0.704 rows=26225 loops=1)
                                                                     Index Cond: ((topic)::text = 'uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state'::text)
                                                         ->  Hash Join  (cost=12971.21..14191.59 rows=235 width=71) (actual time=13.873..13.881 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                               Hash Cond: ((max(mqtt_logs."timestamp")) = m."timestamp")
                                                               InitPlan 4 (returns $3)
                                                                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..1583.05 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.056..0.056 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                                       ->  Index Scan Backward using index_value2s_on_timestamp_and_interval on value2s v2_2  (cost=0.29..4748.56 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.053..0.054 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                                             Index Cond: ("interval" = 86400)
                                                                             Filter: ('uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state'::text = ((((((((organization)::text || '/'::text) || (location)::text) || '/'::text) || (device)::text) || '/'::text) || (measurement)::text) || '/state'::text))
                                                                             Rows Removed by Filter: 11
                                                               ->  HashAggregate  (cost=5122.84..5389.09 rows=8875 width=57) (actual time=4.407..4.411 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                                     Group Key: (to_timestamp(((floor(((EXTRACT(epoch FROM mqtt_logs."timestamp") / '86400'::numeric) + '1'::numeric)) * '86400'::numeric))::double precision) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'::text), mqtt_logs.topic
                                                                     Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 409kB
                                                                     InitPlan 5 (returns $4)
                                                                       ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..1583.05 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.057..0.058 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                                             ->  Index Scan Backward using index_value2s_on_timestamp_and_interval on value2s v2_3  (cost=0.29..4748.56 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.054..0.054 rows=1 loops=1)
                                                                                   Index Cond: ("interval" = 86400)
                                                                                   Filter: ('uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state'::text = ((((((((organization)::text || '/'::text) || (location)::text) || '/'::text) || (device)::text) || '/'::text) || (measurement)::text) || '/state'::text))
                                                                                   Rows Removed by Filter: 11
                                                                     ->  Index Only Scan using index_mqtt_logs_on_topic_and_unit_and_timestamp on mqtt_logs  (cost=0.42..3473.13 rows=8888 width=57) (actual time=1.986..4.081 rows=1703 loops=1)
                                                                           Index Cond: ((topic = 'uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state'::text) AND ("timestamp" >= COALESCE(($4)::timestamp with time zone, '1970-01-01 02:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone)))
                                                                           Heap Fetches: 1703
                                                               ->  Hash  (cost=6154.22..6154.22 rows=8888 width=55) (actual time=9.439..9.439 rows=1703 loops=1)
                                                                     Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 288kB
                                                                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on mqtt_logs m  (cost=310.62..6154.22 rows=8888 width=55) (actual time=8.561..9.106 rows=1703 loops=1)
                                                                           Recheck Cond: ((topic)::text = 'uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state'::text)
                                                                           Filter: ("timestamp" >= COALESCE(($3)::timestamp with time zone, '1970-01-01 02:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone))
                                                                           Rows Removed by Filter: 24522
                                                                           Heap Blocks: exact=5359
                                                                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_mqtt_logs_on_topic_and_unit  (cost=0.00..308.39 rows=26663 width=0) (actual time=0.786..0.786 rows=26225 loops=1)
                                                                                 Index Cond: ((topic)::text = 'uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state'::text)
               SubPlan 1
                 ->  Limit  (cost=722.64..722.64 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=5.566..5.567 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Sort  (cost=722.64..729.13 rows=2598 width=8) (actual time=5.565..5.565 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Sort Key: m5."timestamp" DESC
                             Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
                             ->  Index Only Scan using index_mqtt_logs_on_topic_and_unit_and_timestamp on mqtt_logs m5  (cost=0.42..709.65 rows=2598 width=8) (actual time=0.016..3.575 rows=26225 loops=1)
                                   Index Cond: (topic = (m3.topic)::text)
                                   Heap Fetches: 1888
         ->  Index Only Scan using v2_ind on value2s vs  (cost=0.42..4.32 rows=1 width=45) (never executed)
               Index Cond: ((organization = (split_part((m3.topic)::text, '/'::text, 1))) AND (location = (split_part((m3.topic)::text, '/'::text, 2))) AND (device = (split_part((m3.topic)::text, '/'::text, 3))) AND ("timestamp" = m3.high_margin) AND ("interval" = (86400)) AND (measurement = (split_part((m3.topic)::text, '/'::text, 4))))
               Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.625 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 93
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 4.094 ms, Inlining 16.665 ms, Optimization 376.954 ms, Emission 279.316 ms, Total 677.029 ms
 Execution Time: 712.741 ms
(85 rows)
```

The problem is that I don't understand the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE.

My question is how to identify the bottleneck in the query, and how to improve the query so that it is executed quickly?

Comment: Your query is running in under 1 second (712.741 ms) so why do you think it is slow or there is a bottleneck? If you experience is that it is much slower than this then the bottleneck is likely to be in the network between the server and your client application

Comment: @NickW: It is slow in the sense that it is executed each time a new row is inserted in the database, so 700ms is not fast enough for real time operation. Do you have any suggestion to improve it?

Comment: The first thing to do on these is to drop the `INSERT` part because it is unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focus on where the actual time is spent, and focus on bad row count estimates. The latter are present, but seem harmless, but there is one node where basically all the time is spent:

```
->  Bitmap Heap Scan on mqtt_logs m1  (cost=1893.67..8070.57 rows=8888 width=71) (actual time=681.496..684.538 rows=1703 loops=1)
      Recheck Cond: ((topic)::text = 'uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state'::text)
      Filter: ("timestamp" >= COALESCE(($2)::timestamp with time zone, '1970-01-01 02:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone))
      Rows Removed by Filter: 24522
      Heap Blocks: exact=5359
      InitPlan 3 (returns $2)
        ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..1583.05 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.103..0.104 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  [irrelevant, omitted]
      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_mqtt_logs_on_topic_and_unit  (cost=0.00..308.39 rows=26663 width=0) (actual time=0.704..0.704 rows=26225 loops=1)
            Index Cond: ((topic)::text = 'uowm/uowm_grafeio113/state/total_energy/state'::text)
```

The index is scanned for matches on a certain `topic`, which finds 26225 rows. These 26225 rows have to be looked up in the table, which takes 684 milliseconds and has to read 5359 8 kB-blocks (we cannot tell if the I/O takes long, because you didn't use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`). Then an additional filter on `timestamp` is applied which weeds out all rows except for 8888.

You can probably reduce the time to perhaps a third if you

```
CREATE INDEX ON mqtt_logs (topic, timestamp);
```

because then only the 8888 rows have to be read from the table.

To make the query even faster, so that no row has to be read from the table at all (because everything is in the index), try

```
CREATE INDEX ON mqtt_logs (topic, timestamp) INCLUDE (value);
-- to get an efficient index-only scan
VACUUM mqtt_logs;
```

Comment: This is fantastic, adding this index brought the time down to 10ms!. I am still curious though, how did you determine the node where the time was spent, and how did you determine the needed index? I saw `actual time=681.496..684.538` so I thought that this was run after the slow part of the query.

Comment: True, but there was no other node that took much time. If the startup time is high, that can mean that the bitmap heap scan has a lot to do before it finds the first result row. Perhaps all the rows with a low `timestamp` that get filtered out are early in the table.